# Export with different address

Tags: export, files-and-directories

Is it possible to use the `Export[]` command and add another address other than the usual `Home` directory that is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Export["C:/datafolder/data.txt"]
```

Comment: Yes. I'm working on a mac, I'll try this out!

Answer (score 2):

For convenience you can use `SetDirectory`. For example

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
Export["123.txt",x];
```